# Elemento Superior ao Input

Tags: jquery, css

Bom dia, Pessoal estou colocando uma máscara num campo que formata um numero de telefone, porém podem ver que o ID do campo é #Field_11690, pois foi criado por um plugin do WordPress.

```
( function( $ ) {

// jQuery MeioMask.
$( '#field_11690' ).setMask( '(99) 9999-99999' ).ready( function( event ) {
    var target, phone, element;
    target = ( event.currentTarget ) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof type ) {
        return;
    }
    phone = target.value.replace( /\D/g, '' );
    element = $( target );
    element.unsetMask();
    if ( 10 < phone.length ) {
        element.setMask( '(99) 99999-9999' );
    } else {
        element.setMask( '(99) 9999-99999' );
    }
});
```

E por este motivo não sei se em produção continuaria o mesmo ID, tem alguma outra forma de eu conseguir declarar o numero de ID deste campo, ou pegar algum elemento Superior?

Comment: Bom pelo o que da para ver do ID do campo, acredito que o ID do campo possa ser dinâmico, ou também possa ser fixo, o plugin pode salvar o ID para aquele campo e sempre manter o mesmo. Se for esse o caso tudo bem, seria bom você confirmar.

Caso não for, acredito que o ideal seria você pegar um elemento superior ao campo, como o form, ou até uma div. E encontra-lo via jQuery, acredito que ele deva manter uma hierarquia sempre, independente do ID.

Comment: Podemos te ajudar melhor se você pudesse mostrar em produção como está a hierarquia dos elementos. E também confirmar se o id do campo é alterado de alguma forma, verifique se o plugin salva os dados dos formulário gerados no banco (alguns fazem assim).

Comment: Olá Vinicius, Fiz o teste e em produção ele salva o nome do ID aleatório, porém vi que na div que contém o input tem uma classe que posso usar, como faço para acessar o input com a classe que tem na div?

Comment: Teria como postar o código de hierarquia? Assim posso te exemplificar melhor como chegar até o input a partir dessa div que possui.

Comment: `<div class="editfield field_11690 field_telefone-com-ddd required-field visibility-adminsonly alt field_type_textbox">

Comment: <input id="field_11690" name="field_11690" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-labelledby="field_11690-1" aria-describedby="field_11690-3">`

Comment: Dentro da Div Esta aquele input, consegue me dizer, como acesso ele para colocar na função do jquery lá em cima?

Comment: Vou postar a reposta ali em baixo, consegue me confirmar se a classe 'field_telefone-com-ddd' sempre estará nessa div? E dentro dessa div só fica esse input ou tem mais coisa?

Comment: A Classe, sempre estará sim nesta Div, existe um <legend id="field_11690-1" entre a div e o input, Obrigado pela ajuda, assim que postar eu já testo e marco como resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso dentro da sua DIV como mencionou fique apenas o  você pode chegar o seguinte código para chegar até ele (considerando que a classe que usarei de referência não se altera):

```
$('.field_telefone-com-ddd').find(':input').setMask('(99) 9999-99999').ready(function( event ) {
    var target, phone, element;
    target = ( event.currentTarget ) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof type ) {
        return;
    }
    phone = target.value.replace( /\D/g, '' );
    element = $( target );
    element.unsetMask();
    if ( 10 < phone.length ) {
        element.setMask( '(99) 99999-9999' );
    } else {
        element.setMask( '(99) 9999-99999' );
    }
});
```

Esse código vai capturar todos os elementos ([find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)) do tipo [input](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) dentro do elemento com a classe de referência dentro do `$`, portanto irá funcionar unicamente na sua situação, onde existe apenas um input.

Caso houvesse mais de um input, você também poderia capturar o input de ordem X com:

```
$('.field_telefone-com-ddd').find(':input:eq(X)')
```

Substituindo o 'X' pelo número da ordem do input dentro do elemento de referência.

Comment: Só por motivos de pesquisa posterior, no campo $('field_telefone-com-ddd')m colocar o ponto para indicar que é uma classe.

Comment: OBrigado pela Ajuda :D

Comment: @BrunoAngeoletto realmente, acabei não colocando, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Aprofundando a Resposta do Vinicius acima (que já me garantiu a resposta correta)
Busquei também outra forma de resolver e cheguei no código abaixo.

```
( function( $ ) {
// jQuery MeioMask.
if ($('.field_telefone-com-ddd input').length !== 1) {
    return;
}
$('.field_telefone-com-ddd input').setMask('(99) 9999-99999').ready(function( event ) {
    var target, phone, element;
    target = ( event.currentTarget ) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;
    if ( 'undefined' === typeof type ) {
        return;
    }
    phone = target.value.replace( /\D/g, '' );
    element = $( target );
    element.unsetMask();
    if ( 10 < phone.length ) {
        element.setMask( '(99) 99999-9999' );
    } else {
        element.setMask( '(99) 9999-99999' );
    }
});
```

}( jQuery ) );